# Android: Navigation drawer auto scroll to top behavior on item selection

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Is there any method to stop the navigation drawer list items from going to top on being selection. I have 12 items in navigation drawer menu which has a scrollview implemented as it will definitely need it, I have selected the item at position 3 it take that position to the top of screen and hide the above items and if i have to see the above items always i have to scroll down. Any method how to get ride of this auto scroll up behavior on item selection.

Comment: are u using listview in the navigation drawer ?

Comment: @Nithinlal yes i am using listview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was actually using a listener with switch statement what I was doing was setting the property of mDrawerList.setSelection(position); so simply I have commented this line and everything is fine.